# Does $a^2 = b^2$ imply $|a| = |b|$?

Tags: proof-explanation, absolute-value

This seems like a rather obvious fact, but I can't figure out how to prove (or disprove) it.

Suppose $a, b, \in \mathbb{R}$, and $a^2 = b^2$. If I take square roots, I get $a = |b|$ and $b = |a|$. I want to conclude that $|a| = |b|$, and this seems to be rather obviously true, but I can't seem to get it via substitution. Perhaps the solution is to consider cases and prove that $|a| - |b| \geq 0$ and $|b| - |a| \geq 0$.

Comment: Note:  $||a||=|a|$ (idempotence)

Comment: I am ok with that, but since taking absolute values doesn't preserve equalities, I don't know how to prove that. (Or does it? Perhaps I am thinking of inequalities.)

Comment: $|a| = \sqrt{a^2}$, so taking the square root on both sides of $a^2=b^2$ implies $|a|=|b|$.

Comment: John:  Doesn’t $a^2=b^2$ imply $\sqrt{a^2}=\sqrt{b^2}$?

Comment: I should have realized it was that easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$a^2=b^2$$

$$a^2-b^2=0$$

$$(a-b)(a+b)=0$$

$$a=b \textrm{ or } a=-b$$

In either case:  $$|a|=|b|$$

Comment: clear, cut concise!

Answer (score 3):

$a^2=b^2\implies\sqrt{a^2}=\sqrt{b^2}\implies|a|=|b|$